# How to update an excel cell using based on its content using Java and Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a predefined excel file which is a kind of form where most of the information is already mentioned but I have to just enter the Name, Address, etc details from my application made in Java.

I can store the cell (like A12, B20, etc) and update those cells using Apache POI libraries and methods easily. But I want it to be dynamic. Like if the users changes the name cell from A12 to B12, the Java code should not be modified.

Is there a way we can store some vaiable name in the excel cell and update the value of that cell from Java ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CellReference](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellReference.html#CellReference%28java.lang.String%29)

```
String sUserInput = "A1"; // A1 or whatever
CellReference ref = new CellReference (sUserInput);
ref.getRow ();
ref.getCol ();
```

Comment: Thanks @LiuYan for the response. But I dont want the sUserInput = "A1" all the time. If the customer changes the template of the excel file(like change the field for total of the A column from A50 to A51), then there should not be any change in the java code.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a cron job to read the excel file with a particular intervel and compare the cells values with the previous values.